# php fetching results after stmt prepare and execute statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to do an search query in SQL, using AJAX to change a div tag into the result of the search. However, I have not been able to get the query running with stmt binding params (for security). By printing variable I found that all parts is working, but I think either the params are not searching properly, or the get_result is used incorrectly. The reason I say that is, when printing in the while loop, the output is always "()". By the way, the table that it is pulling from has more than 20 columns

Please see the code below:

```
<?php
$q = $_GET['q'];

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','password','my_db');
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}


$stmt=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE firstGroup=? OR secondGroup=? OR thirdGroup=?");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $q, $q, $q);
if($stmt->execute()){
$stmt->bind_result($name, $code);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $name, $code);
    }
}else{
echo "Didn't work";
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon recommendation by tillz, I tried several commands in my DBMS. I ended up finding that the correct SQL operator was actually the "LIKE" operator.

The correct PHP code is given below:

```
<?php
$q = $_GET['q'];

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','password','my_db');
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}


$stmt=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE firstGroup LIKE ? OR secondGroup LIKE ? OR thirdGroup LIKE ?");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $q, $q, $q);
if($stmt->execute()){
$stmt->bind_result($name, $code);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $name, $code);
    }
}else{
echo "Didn't work";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please, please avoid using "select *".
You'll run into problems with this.

- mysqli will only work if you do bind_result for *all* columns.
- if you change your database, all bind_result parts must be edited.
- It's less performant.
- you can't see which columns are bound to which variables without having a look at the database schema

Instead, use

```
$stmt=$con->prepare("SELECT `name`,`code` FROM Contacts WHERE firstGroup=? OR secondGroup=? OR thirdGroup=?");
```

This problem should be solved with this.
If you want it easier to change the selected colums, see [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php#102179) on php.net for using an array and call bind_result for every element.
Then you could easily change the query to

```
$colums=Array("name","code","firstGroup");
$stmt=$con->prepare("SELECT `".implode("`,`",$columns)."` FROM Contacts WHERE firstGroup=? OR secondGroup=? OR thirdGroup=?");
```

And it's very easy to configure the selected columns while avoiding the above Problems (in this case, added "firstGroup").

Comment: I tried it out, but instead of printing the '()', now its printing the names of the columns I input. :(

Comment: I guess the fetching is going wrong for some reason.

Comment: Did you probably use single Quotes ( ' ) insted of Backticks ( ` ) for the column names? Did you try the query in a database manager (phpMyAdmin).

Comment: I didnt try it in the DBMS, but I did try the quotes. Ill try the DBMS and let you know what I get!

Comment: I tried to check it in the DBMS, and it was giving an empty set. So I tried the LIKE command, and it works perfectly! Thanks for the advice on the DBMS!